# I can't center my map on geolocation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

im having some trouble gettimg my map to center and zoom on the user's geolocation. I tried to pass (lat, lng) into the "center:" argument and i get a blank screen.
 Here's my code.

```
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: mylat, lng: mylng},
      zoom: 14
    });
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          mylat: position.coords.latitude,
          mylng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        map.setCenter(pos);
        zoom: 13

      },
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  The posted code contains syntax errors: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var`

Comment: Yes sir, edited out all irrelevant code. My problem appears when i try to pass my lat long variables into the center function

Comment: If i use regular coordinates the page loads fine

Comment: I would expect another javascript error with the posted code as `mylat` and `mylng` are not defined.  Please provide a (working) [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  LatLng object  instead of literalLatLng

```
 map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude));
```

however the literLatLng require lat, lng (not myLat, myLng)

```
 var pos = {
     lat: position.coords.latitude,
     lng: position.coords.longitude
    };
```